# Is there a more common term for "hemigroup"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, definition

In *The Number System* by Thurston the author introduces an algebraic structure he calls a "hemigroup".  It doesn't appear to be a very common usage.  The laws of a hemigroup are:

- (i)   $\left(x*y\right)*z=x*\left(y*z\right)$
- (ii)  $\left(x*y\right)=\left(y*x\right)$
- (iii) $\left(x*y\right)=\left(x*z\right)\implies{y=z}$
- (iv)  $\exists_e e*e=e$

Apparently there are other definitions for the same term.  Is there a more common term than "hemigroup" for this kind of structure?

Comment: Typo in (ii)? [And a small typo in (iv)].

Comment: Unless my eyes are plying tricks on me, The laws are stated consistently with the book.  (i)associative; (ii)commutative; (iii) cancellation; (iv) neutral element.

Comment: Okay, so commutativity is: $(x*y) = (y*x)$ (you've written $(y*z)$ instead of $(y*x)$, unless it's my eyes that are playing tricks on me!) : D

Comment: I suspect that your eyes are indeed plying tricks.

Comment: I don't know if this helps much, but it appears to be a commutative monoid with identity.

Comment: @GaryMoon An example given was that of the natural numbers including 0 with standard addition.  Another was the natural numbers excluding 0 with standard multiplication.

Comment: @GaryMoon monoid means "semigroup with identity", so "monoid with identity" means "semigroup with identity with identity".

Comment: A monoid does of course have an id element by definition. I should have said a commutative monoid with the cancellation property. My mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is usually called a *cancellative commutative monoid*.  Note that in the presence of (iii), (iv) is equivalent to saying that $e$ is a (left) identity, so these axioms just say you have a commutative associative operation with an identity element (i.e., a commutative monoid) which satisfies the cancellation axiom (iii).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: It's equivalent in conjunction with the other axioms. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3201060/86856